# Washing Machine Grease on white towel

Tags: cleaning

I have a black stain on my white cotton dish towel, this towel says on the tag it can not be bleached. I think it may have come from my washing machine, but I am not for sure. I have already tried ice and Biz as well as washing it again. This towel is for decoration and I really need it to make my kitchen pretty again :( Please Help.

Comment: It  might be grease or from a rubber seal. In either case, try an organic solvent such as Lestoil. See http://web.extension.illinois.edu/stain/

Answer (score 2):

If by using detergent and grasping both sides aggressively agitating, grinding left and right against each other, you cannot remove it, then you probably have to go nuclear.  White cotton should be bleachable, ignore warning.  Next is excise, paint, patch or crop.

Comment: The 'do not bleach' warning on towels is added to all regardless of colour. White cotton can be bleached. And if your towel is not useful as is, just try it.

Answer (score 1):

Any time I get oil or other difficult to remove stains on my clothes I use washing up liquid (or dish soap) to remove them. The soap in the washing up liquid breaks down the oil and makes it easier to remove.

Try using a bit of soap massaged into the stain with a soft bristled toothbrush. The apply a but more soap, leave to soak for a few minutes and wash the towel again.

If you think the mark is being caused by you washing machine you should do a few empty washes with just detergent and water to clean the machine - otherwise things will just get stained again.

Answer (score 1):

If it's grease, I would try brake cleaner, its always worked miracles for me and typically comes in either chlorinated or non-chlorinated type

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you following steps before washing it again:

1. Take the towel soaked in soap water that is ready for washing
2. Apply some liquid from stain remover like this

[image: Plastic bottle]

3. Off course, you can go for a substitute for this that is available in your market, do not think that I am branding this product.
4. Take care not to make contact with this liquid with the bare hand. For this, hold the towel in your hand, pour some liquid and try rubbing it against each other until you see the stain gets removed.
5. If required, you can apply liquid again and repeat this until change occurs.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a paper instead of white cloth! (*don't let it use too much or the grease will be back inside!*)            :)

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question of removing grease.

Comment: This does not provide a hack for the problem provided, try improving the answer @JakeJoshuaZGuzman